# Where to ask for advice on purchasing components?

Tags: support

I believe in the rules/ policies of using the normal Electronics Stack Exchange site, I'm not allowed to ask for "shopping or buying recommendation". Where would I be able to ask for advice, recommendations or alternatives to components that are obsolete?

Comment: Try our [EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).  The rules are more relaxed there.

Comment: *"Where to ask for advice on purchasing components?"*  Not here.  Otherwise, we are not the help desk for the internet.

Comment: Manufacturers, distributors can be good at finding replacement parts

Answer (score 3):

While shopping questions are off topic, there are questions related to how to find a component that are on topic.

"Where can I buy a diode to use in this circuit?" is thus a bad question, but "I don't understand how to select a diode for this circuit.  What parameters and specs do I need to pay attention to, and why?" is a very good question.  "How do I use the filtering tools on Retailer X's site to find this?" might be straddling the line.

As comments have indicated, all of this is fine for the chat, where I've gone for such resources with fair regularity.